# operation of AODV when an intermediate node receives multiple rreq packets from the source

Tags: network-protocols, ad-hoc-network

I have a question about the operation of AODV when an intermediate node receives multiple rreq packets from the source.
what happens?
did he discard it because of source and broadcast id is equal or not, he processes it?